# C# Datatable sorting date DESC

Tags: c#

I am displaying a list of items in a data grid binded to dt_pdc. The DueDate column shows the date of the cheque, as day, month and year. When i'm sorting using descending, it does the following:
Date List & Order:
1---4/18/2020
2---4/2/2020
3---4/22/2020

When the day's first digit is less than another day's first digit, it is being sorted first, in the example, 18 april is coming before 2 april, however 22 april comes after 2 april.

Is there anything that i can fix in the sorting view, or do i have to write it in the DB as 02 instead of 2.

```
dt_pdc.Columns.Add("ID");
dt_pdc.Columns.Add("ChequeNumber");
dt_pdc.Columns.Add("DueDate");
dt_pdc.Columns.Add("Amount");


dt_pdc.Merge(Database.Accounts.Cheques.getPDCChequesSearch(dt_pdc));
dt_pdc.DefaultView.Sort = "DueDate ASC";
```

Comment: I guess it's doing a string sort, as you haven't given a type for the column. Try something like dt_pdc.Columns.Add("DueDate", typeof(DateTime))

Answer (score 1):

> or do i have to write it in the DB as 02

no, that's just compounding the error (wait until you get an urgent support call on new year's day if you don't believe me); basically: **stop storing dates as strings**; store them as *dates* - i.e. `DateTime`; then everything will work *correctly*. If you absolutely must use `string` for some reason (and it would need to be a good reason), consider using ISO8601 format, i.e. store it as `"2020-04-02"`; this is then sortable naturally as a string, plus it is unambiguous (there is no question as to whether this is the 2nd of April or the 4th of February).

Comment: It is stored as DateTime in the database, however from the code i never set the type of the datatable column. Now i've added the typeof(DateTime) when adding the DueDate column, and it works properly using Sort only (without "DESC")

Comment: Doing the above was displaying the time which i did not want so i had to remove it. I just changed the date to the format mentioned above when fetching it from the database.                         row["DueDate"] = x.DueDate.ToString("yyyy-M-dd") from                         row["DueDate"] = x.DueDate.ToShortDateString().